# Running a single test in maven -> No tests were executed

Tags: java, testing, selenium, maven, functional-testing

When I run a single test in Maven with this command:

```
mvn test -Dtest=InitiateTest
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
No tests were executed!
```

It worked a couple of minutes ago, but now it stopped working for some reason. I tried running `mvn clean` a couple of times before running the test, it doesn't help.

The test looks like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class InitiateTest {

    public static FirefoxDriver driver;

    @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void initiateTest() throws Exception {
            driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login.jsp");
            ...
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It's caused by adding this dependency to POM:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
   <version>2.0b1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I remove it, everything works fine. Everything works fine even when I add these two dependencies instead of the previous one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
   <version>2.0b1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
   <version>2.0b1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is weird.

Comment: What kind of test are you trying to run? You did not put an @Ignore by any chance?

Comment: Probably not too helpful..but remember, both those are beta products and mightily subject to breaking all over the place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably picking up JUnit3 on your classpath somewhere, which effectively disables JUnit4.

Run `mvn dependency:tree` to find out where it's coming in from and add exclude if from the dependency.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you are seeing [this bug,](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-827) which is said to affect surefire 2.12 but not 2.11?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was running into. I ended up using 2.12.3 which contains a fix.

Comment: Seconded, 2.12.3 contained the fix for this.

Comment: Apparently also 2.19.1 carries the bug :(

Comment: it helps me too, really caused by the testng conflict with selenium internal version . thanks . take to use surefire 2.19.1 ,no problem now .

Comment: Link is dead and no summary in answer, so this answer is almost pointless now.

Comment: With 2.19.1 I was able to run a single test, with 2.19 I've got the "No tests were executed!" error.

Comment: fixed the link.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It was caused by testng dependency that came with junit3. Just add a exclusion statement for it and tests should work.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
  <version>2.0b1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It was the same for me a minute a go... or an hour before I found this :/ THX man

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when trying to use `@org.junit.Test`

with

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The correct annotation to be used is `@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

Comment: wow! didn't expect this at all, and yes, the automatic imports fix makes it easy to import org.junit.Test - what is this Jupiter API anyway? :/

Answer (score 3):

I have changed "maven-surefire-plugin" to 2.14.1 version (from 2.12) and it helped

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem adding jtestr dependency. It turns out one of its dependencies was picking up junit-3.8.1. I solved it using the exclusion statement below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jtestr</groupId>
  <artifactId>jtestr</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  <version>0.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was running a single test using mvn test -Dtest=MyTest. My mistake was that the only test had its @test annotation commented out so no test was being found in the file by junit. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

changed from 2.6 to 2.18.1 and things work now

Answer (score 1):

In the build session of the pom.xml, include this:

```
 <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.14.1</version>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: indeed my pom.xml was missing maven-surefire-plugin entry entirely, so I skipped the other suggestions about the plugin versions - my bad

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. So I had to **build the project from project's root level** using

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=True
```

And then **run the test command from the directory where test package's pom** was residing

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestClass
```

Also make sure that value of skip option is true. For example in my pom file, the default value of skip is true.

```
 <properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

So when I run the maven test, I set it to false

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestUserUpdate* -DskipTests=false
```

Answer (score 1):

update the org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin to 2.22.0, it was resolved.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.Please note this type of answer should be in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try running maven in debug mode. It might give you more information.

```
mvn -X -Dtest=InitiateTest test
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when duplicating and refactoring a test from a different class.

The issue was annotating a `private` method with `@Test`, causing it to be ignored, changing to `public` fixed the issue. :facepalm:

```
    @Test
    public void testImportOrderItems() {
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe as useless as my last attempt, but I just read a JUnit 4 test class should import org.junit.Test.* **and org.junit.Assert.*** to be considered so.
As you don't have the Assert import, it might be worth trying this quickly just to be sure...

Answer (score -2):

```
mvn test -Dtest='xxxx.*Test' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true  -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

I have meet the same question that No tests were executed!
My suggestion is add another paramters that `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true  -DfailIfNoTests=false` can solve it.

Comment: Ensuring that the error is not ignored does absolutely nothing to prevent the error from occurring.

Answer (score -3):

I don't really how the @Test annotation processes your test, but can you try prefixing your test method with "test"?

```
public void testInit() throws Exception {
      driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login.jsp");
      ...
}
```

Comment: @Test annotation was introduced in jUnit 4, in jUnit 3 every method had to start with "test"

Comment: yep, that unfortunately doesn't help. @Test annotation is enough.