# maven run junit test

Tags: java, maven

I'm having trouble compiling and running JUnit tests using a maven project.

In the pom.xml I added those lines to configure the surfire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>                    
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>                                 
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Client*.java</include>
                </includes>   
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

the tests classes are under the path "src/test/java//".

When I run the command `mvn test` I obtain this output:

```
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: trunk
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 10 resources
[INFO] [cxf-codegen:wsdl2java {execution: generate-sources}]
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: unit-test}]
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
```

I really can't figure out where I'm wrong.

**EDIT:**
I changed the pom configuration as follows, because I also noticed that the tests classes were also not compiled:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/target/*.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes> 
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In this way maven start to consider my test sources and try to compile it, even if it fails to compile them because I have generated code with cxf-codegen-plugin, that test compilation seems not to see it.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that no test case matches `**/Client*.java`.

Make sure the pattern is correct. Also `mvn -X` (enable debug output) might give you some hints as to why Maven can't locate any tests.

Comment: All the test classes are under their package directory. Have I to specify it or "**" is enough? running mvn -X didn't give me more hints.

Comment: Names of test classes should end with "Test". The default pattern is `**/*Test.java`. If you want all files, the pattern should be `**/*.java`

Comment: Thank you very much, I substituted my **/Client*.java with **/*.java

Answer (score 1):

If you are following Maven default structure (code in src/main/java, tests in src/test/java), you do not need any specific configuration in your pom.xml (test goals are built in Maven).

Try removing the specific surefire config and just running:

```
mvn test
```

Comment: I added the surefire configuration because test still didn't work, hoping to solve the problem.

Comment: "Tests didn't work": was the error message the same (no test to run)? Can you post your project' structure? mvn test should be enough.

Comment: the error message was "tests are skipped", for this reason I decided to configure surfire in the pom.xml. The project structure is the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a maven surefire plugin defect as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10339820/4420532) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26988097/4420532).

- see [SUREFIRE-827](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-827)
- and [SUREFIRE-1028](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1028)