# Maven with Surefire refuses to run single test method?

Tags: java, maven, junit, surefire

I've been trying to use Maven with the Surefire plugin to run some JUnit unit tests.

Following the instructions provided by Maven and the Surefire folks here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

My command for maven is as follows:

```
mvn clean -Dtest-group=regression -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod test
```

TestGroup is pulled from an @IfProfileValue statement and has always worked:

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "test-group", values = {"regression"})
```

However after I run the command, despite being sure that testClass has a method named testMethod(which would run if I didn't add the #testMethod to the command) my output is as follows:

```
~/REPOS/app: mvn clean -Dtest-group=regression -Dtest=TestClass#testmethod test

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.app:GuiAuto:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:jar -> version 2.2.4 vs [3.0,) @ line 127, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 147, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GuiAuto 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ GuiAuto ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/llaskin/REPOS/app/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ GuiAuto ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 92 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ GuiAuto ---
[INFO] Compiling 762 source files to /Users/llaskin/REPOS/app/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ GuiAuto ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ GuiAuto ---
[INFO] Compiling 762 source files to /Users/llaskin/REPOS/app/target/test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ GuiAuto ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/llaskin/REPOS/app/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=false, threadCount=5, useUnlimitedThreads=false, threadCountSuites=0, threadCountClasses=0, threadCountMethods=0, parallelOptimized=true

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.379s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 17 12:27:59 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/571M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project GuiAuto: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: You don't even mention where `@IfProfileValue` comes from. If it is Spring, the issue might be caused by Spring rather than JUnit or Maven. There is no `spring` label on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is because of the bug [SUREFIRE-1028](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-1028) in Surefire 2.16 and 2.17. This bug is fixed in Surefire 2.18.

Can you please upgrade and tell us whether your problem is fixed with Surefire 2.18 or not.