# Running single JUnit4 test in Eclipse with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, junit

When writing tests, I'd like to run them individually. Howver, since I have switched from the default Eclipse Java builder to Maven, this is not possible any more. Observations:

1. Until today I could open a JUnit test source file and select `Run as | JUnit test` from the toolbar. Before I migrated to Maven, Eclipse built the unit test when needed.
2. Since Maven, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` in case I have not explicitly compiled the tests before. I can bypass this if I select the POM and do `Run as | Maven test`. This will compile the tests and run all tests.
3. If I select the unit test again and choose `Run as | JUnit test` from the toolbar now, it'll execute the test.

Since this is way too unconvenient, I'd like the "old" behavior back and I think this should only be a configuration problem.

I have

- read [Running a single test in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646307/running-a-single-junit-test-in-eclipse), but it describes a problem without Maven. Basically, the expected behavior is what I had before.
- read [Running JUnit tests with Maven under Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451808/running-junit-tests-with-maven-under-eclipse) is what I currently have. I have Surefire and I can run all the tests when selecting the POM.
- my [Surefire version is 2.18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979620/maven-with-surefire-refuses-to-run-single-test-method)
- converted my project's directory structure to the default Maven layout (which it wasn't before)
- [Running a single test in Maven - No tests were executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646014/running-a-single-test-in-maven-no-tests-were-executed) is not applicable, because I want to run tests from Eclipse, not from command line.
- [x] Build autmatically enabled
- [x] Maven project Builder is configured in project properties
- The [mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg03823.html) stops unresolved
- read about [Surefire arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392926/maven-surefire-arguments-when-running-junit-test-via-eclipse)

I'm giving up now.

**How can I do efficient red-green refactoring, i.e. run only one unit test at a time without adding a run configuration for each single test?**

Comment: In general this is possible. I think you have a configuration problem with your Maven/Eclipse integration. Do both (Maven and Eclipse) use the same target directory (i.e. where the .class files are stored)?

Comment: @Jan: In Java Build File, I have "Default output folder" set to /target/classes. The source folders point there (/src/main/java, /src/main/resources) except the unit tests (src/test/java) which point to /target/test-classes.

Comment: In my POM I have removed and specific directory names, so it builds to /target/classes and /target/test-classes as well.

Comment: How did you "_switch from the default Eclipse Java builder to Maven_" in detail? Did you try to • create a clean new Maven project • copy the main/test sources/resources into it • adapt the `pom.xml` accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found out that the Java Builder was disabled:

[image: Java Builder not configured]

Enabling it returned the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me-

1. Select the test file you want to run.
2. Right click and open run configuration.
3. Now go to classpath and move maven dependencies to the top and apply.